# js function not running

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

my js function is perfectly working (without master page) i just needed to use it on anther page so i copy paste it in a new web form but this time using master page and now it's not running at all..that's my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"  
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" CodeBehind="homecarecontent.aspx.vb"  
 Inherits="homecare_web2.homecarecontent" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    #TextArea1
    {
        height: 152px;
        width: 222px;
    }
    #conte
    {
        height: 136px;
        width: 229px;
    }
    #content_txt
    {            height: 178px;
        width: 226px;
    }
    #content_t
    {
        height: 159px;
        width: 225px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function limiter() {
        var area = document.getElementById("content_txt");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");
        var maxLength = 160;
        var checkLength = function () {
            if (area.value.length <= maxLength) {
                message.innerHTML = (maxLength - area.value.length) + " characters remainging";
            }
        }
        setInterval(checkLength, 300);
    }
  </script>

 </head>
```

and that's my asp code:

```
<td valign='top'>
                <textarea style="resize:none; margin-bottom:0px;" id="content_txt" class="area"
                    name="TextArea1" runat="server" maxlength="160" onkeyup="return limiter();" ></textarea>
            </td>
```

any help plz  !

Comment: it tried.. still nth !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Control.ClientID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) Property.

```
var area = document.getElementById('<%=content_txt.ClientID%>');
var message = document.getElementById('<%=message.ClientID%>');
```

If you still face the problem, then see the Console tab of `FireBug` in `FireFox`. You will find the description of the Errors there.

Comment: area is null ! that's the error that i'm facing but in reality the is not null !

Comment: Can you check what is the `id` of that `content_txt` control in rendered html by the help of `FireBug`?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the runat attribute of your textarea to

```
runat="client"
```

Answer (score 0):

when we do use master pages id of control changes thats why it is not able to find the elements on the page and not working and resulting errors so i should put :

```
var area = document.getElementById('<%=content_txt.ClientID%>');
```